# google maps api 3 MouseEvent latLng

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, mouseevent

I am trying to use google maps as the tool for pinpointing a location. I am using javaScript api v3 for that purpose. I am using [ipinfodb](http://www.infodb.com) api for geolocation also. I ran into a problem which I susspect is an API problem, but maby I am forgetting something...
Here is a part of my code:

```
var googleMap = null; // of type google.maps.Map
var googleApiKey = <myGoogleApiKey>;
var scriptLoaded = false;
var latLng = null; // expecting format: "lat,lng" or "(lat,lng)"
var marker = null; // of type google.maps.Marker

function setLatLong(locationStr){
    if (null != locationStr && locationStr.length>2){
        latLng = ""+locationStr;
    if (null != googleMap){
            var ll = latLng.split(","); 
            ll[0] = ll[0].replace(/\(/i,"");
            ll[1] = ll[1].replace(/\)/i,"");
            //TODO: write ll[0], and ll[1] somewhere
        }
    }
}

function loadGoogleMapsScript() {
    if (!scriptLoaded){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+ 
                     googleApiKey+"&sensor=false&callback=initGoogleMaps";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        scriptLoaded = true;
    }
}

function initGoogleMaps() {
var llArray = null;
if (null != latLng) llArray = latLng.split(",");
else  llArray = [0,0];

if (null == googleMap){
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( (llArray && llArray.length == 2)? parseFloat(llArray[0]) : null, 
                                        (llArray && llArray.length == 2)? parseFloat(llArray[1]) : null ),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        draggable:true
      };
      googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("theMapId"), mapOptions);
      google.maps.event.addListener(googleMap, 'click', function(event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
      setTimeout('placeMarker(googleMap.getCenter())',500);
} else{
      googleMap.setZoom(13);
      googleMap.setCenter((llArray && llArray.length == 2)? parseFloat(llArray[0]) : null, 
                          (llArray && llArray.length == 2)? parseFloat(llArray[1]) : null );
}
}

function placeMarker(location) {
    if ( !isNaN(location.lat()) && !isNaN(location.lng()) )
        setLatLong("("+location.lat()+","+location.lng()+")");
    else return null;
    if (marker){
        marker.setMap(null);
        marker.setMap(googleMap);
        marker.setPosition(location);
     } else{
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map:googleMap,
            clickable:false,
            draggable:true
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });
    }
}
```

I start with the call of loadGoogleMapsScript() when I open pop-up div which is removed from the page when the job finishes.
Everything works perfectly, but sometimes, the map goes crazy. If I do not change position of the marker, next time (in the same session) I try to open pop-up div the value of MouseEvent.lat() related to onclick event of map becomes NaN and the marker moves slightly toward top of map. The map could not be dragged correctly.
This is what I use for Pop-up removal:

```
function removePopupDiv(){
    jQuery('.popup_div-area').remove();
//setTimeout("removeScriptBySrcContent('https://maps.g');removeScriptBySrcContent('.googleapis');",300);
    scriptLoaded = false;
    googleMap = null;
    marker = null;
}
```

As you can see I even have tried to remove added script tags but without success, the problem is appearing sometimes.
I am trying to solve this for some time, but without success. Does anybody had this problem before? I cannot find anybody else complains about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake... I should have clear string with longitude and latitude data from any unwanted charachters every time the value is set. Now everything works as a charm.

```
function setLatLong(locationStr){
    if (null != locationStr && locationStr.length>2){
        latLng = ""+locationStr;
            latLng = latLng.replace(/\(/g,"");
            latLng = latLng.replace(/\)/g,"");
            latLng = latLng.replace(/ */g,"");
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Google developers have a site with demo's and they have [one](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/getlatlng.html) which may be of use.

Before developing a Google Map application you should study the [basics](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) before continuing

Comment: Thanks, but it was my mistake in the first place. I have corrected some code and it is now working wery well.